# Trying to replace characters in a .NET form from a textbox

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms-designer

I'm trying to take an input string from a textbox and replace it with a preassigned cipher, and it isn't working. Here's my code:

```
public string Encode(string input)
{
    int counter = 0;
    string output = "";
    List<string> inputlist = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h",
    "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z" };
    List<string> cipherlist = new List<string> { "r","s","n","e","p","h","c","a","t","i","m","g","l",
    "x","w","v","f","u","j","z","k","o","b","y","d","q"};
    do
    {
        output = input.Replace(inputlist[counter], cipherlist[counter]);
        counter++;
    } while (counter < 26);
    return output;
}
```

```
private void btnConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = Encode(textBox1.Text);
}
```

Basically, the label just shows the exact text that I entered in the box when I debug it. What's going on?

Comment: "_Basically, the label just shows the exact text that I entered_". Not exactly. It does show the result of the last attempted input.Replace operation, that replaces "z" in the **input string** with "q". So, if your input string would contain `z` characters, like "zulu" for example, then the label would show "qulu". Why is that so? Debug every single iteration of your while-loop line-by-line, and study carefully what every line does and how variable values change (or not change)...

Comment: By the way, you cannot use string.Replace for what you try to achieve, because it will replace all occurences of a character or substring at once in the **entire** string. So, as an example: your code attempts to replace all `a`'s with `r`. Then later it will attempt to replace those `r`'s which were originally `a`'s with whatever is the cipher character for `r`. Basically, the string.Replace approach will destroy already replaced/encrypted characters...

Comment: *"how did I not see that"*. Because you didn't bother to debug your code. If you had actually debugged, i.e. set a breakpoint, stepped through the code and examined the state at each step, then you would have seen it. You MUST debug your code before posting here. You need to be able to tell us EXACTLY where and how the behaviour of the code doesn't meet your expectations, not just that the end result is not what you expect. If you don't know how to debug, stop what you're doing and learn. There are tutorials available on that specifically.

Answer (score 1):

What you are currently doing is wasting time in a loop that ultimately only replaces all instances of 'z' with 'q'. Even if you changed your code to initialize `string output = input;`, then changed the line in your loop to `output = output.Replace(inputlist[counter], cipherlist[counter]);` it still would not work as you intend. For example, all instances of 'a' would be replaced with 'k', not 'r', as first 'a' would become 'r', which would become 'u', which would finally become 'k' before leaving loop. What you need to do is iterate through your string one character at a time, replacing each character with its cipher value. Additionally, I would recommend rather than using `List<string>`s, you would be better off using a `Dictionary<char, char>`. Using a dictionary enables quick lookup of a character to determine its cipher value.

```
public string Encode(string input)
{
    // if input is null, output is null
    if (input == null) return null;

    // initialize output and cipher
    var output = new StringBuilder(input.Length);
    var cipher = new Dictionary<char, char>
    {
        { 'a', 'r' },
        { 'b', 's' },
        { 'c', 'n' },
        { 'd', 'e' },
        { 'e', 'p' },
        { 'f', 'h' },
        { 'g', 'c' },
        { 'h', 'a' },
        { 'i', 't' },
        { 'j', 'i' },
        { 'k', 'm' },
        { 'l', 'g' },
        { 'm', 'l' },
        { 'n', 'x' },
        { 'o', 'w' },
        { 'p', 'v' },
        { 'q', 'f' },
        { 'r', 'u' },
        { 's', 'j' },
        { 't', 'z' },
        { 'u', 'k' },
        { 'v', 'o' },
        { 'w', 'b' },
        { 'x', 'y' },
        { 'y', 'd' },
        { 'z', 'q' }
    };

    // cipher each character in input
    foreach (char c in input)
    {
        try
        {
            // append next ciphered character to output
            output.Append(cipher[c]);
        }
        catch (KeyNotFoundException)
        {
            // cipher does not exist for given character! leave character as-is?
            output.Append(c);
        }
    }

    // return output
    return output.ToString();
}
```